# Next.Js http://localhost:3000 "localhost refused to connect"

Tags: next.js

I am working on Next.js version "next": "13.3.0", I started my Next.js server with "npm run dev" it starts on localhost:3000 but when I click on the localhost:3000 I get error "localhost refused to connect". I didn't know how to tackle the problem.

I have searched in Task Manager whether any application using this port but I couldn't find any application that is working on port 3000.
I also didn't know how to change the port so that I can run my next js project/app on any port like localhost:4000.

Answer (score 0):

I switched off my windows firewall then i run the next js app by npm run dev and my application start working. i think windows firewall was stopping my application to run at localhost:3000.

if anyone have better approch then kindly tell me to run the next.js app at localhost:3000 by keeping the windows firewall on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).